# How to run Android (command line) application in PHP script?

Tags: php, android

On my Android phone are a Web Server with PHP-plugin, and are a simple HelloWorld application. In Android Terminal Emulator run this application:

am start -n com.hello/.Android_HelloWorldActivity

So this very good. I wrote a PHP script, but my problem is, that with PHP script no start application:

```
<?php echo("Hello World!"); $output = shell_exec('am start -n com.hello/.Android_HelloWorldActivity'); echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; ?>
```

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If you find a response helpful, please up vote it. If a particular response answers your question please click the checkmark next to the response to accept the answer.

Comment: Is `am` in the path of whatever shell PHP is using? You might have to specify an absolute `/full/path/to/am` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you run through the web server will be run as user www-data.  This user most likely does not have permissions to run 'am'.  If you are just running a webserver outside of an application then I don't think you can do this unless you change what user the webserver (apache?) runs as.

If you are running the web server inside of an application then you might try registering a javascript function in Java using [addJavascriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) and then calling this from your webpage to invoke a Java function where you can then perform the needed ... whatever.